# What sefer is being cited here?

Tags: sources-mekorot

I’ve been learning about the concept of עצם as it relates to עצם, נהר, גן.  ענ״ג.

This has taken me to [Sefer Kehillat Yaacov by Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles, ערך עץ and the word עצם.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44143&st=&pgnum=221)

For those checking the link, it is first column, the word עצם immediately below עצבות.

He makes a citation with a detailed quotation which I want to see in the original text. The citation is as follows:

עצם בע״ח שער ס״ג שער פרקי היכלות פ״ב כ׳ דעור בשר גיד עצם כו׳

It sounds like he is citing Eitz Chaim of Rabbi Chaim Vital. But Eitz Chaim only has 50 Gates and none with a title remotely like the one quoted. Nothing dealing with Heichalot at all.

Ramak in Pardes Rimonim has a section on Heichalot, but not divided like the citation and not dealing with that subject.

Can anyone point me to the correct sefer Rabbi Yolles is quoting, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely עץ חיים and number could’ve been a typo. Maybe כ״ג or מ״ג. Or just a wrong number gate altogether. But (more) likely it’s two different references; IOW a comma after ס״ג and שער פרקי היכלות is a separate source.

Comment: There is Pirkei Heichalot Ravati but dont see that concept mentioned,Bais Shaar Hakaavanot (Baal HaSulam) brings such concepts u refer.

Comment: @sam I have multiple editions of the source you are citing & checked them before asking here.

Comment: @Oliver If I weren’t dealing with Rabbi Yolles and this particular sefer of his, I would agree with you. But he is extremely meticulous. I have never found a misquote by him. Another associate I contacted about this thought perhaps it was an earlier edition that doesn’t follow the format we have today. He suggested looking at editions prior to 1850, which I did. At Hebrewbooks, the earlier editions follow the same format we have today for Eitz Chaim by Rabbi Chaim Vital.

Comment: For anyone interested, I also tried searching for the words of the actual quotation he brings in Hebrew via Sefaria & the internet in general. I got no hits. This is a tough one!

Comment: @YaacovDeane “... I would agree with you. But he is extremely meticulous.” And yet there’s dozens of corrections listed at the end of his sefer. This stuff happens.

Comment: In the new edition it explicitly says "Eitz Chaim". https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vhXH.jpg

Comment: @Alex I would suspect they just expanded the original Roshei Teivot. But the Gate number and Gate name don’t exist in Eitz Chaim by Rabbi Chaim Vital. And you have to keep in mind that Rabbi Yolles lived between 1778-1825. Whatever he was looking at was from then or before.

Comment: It was published in 3 volumes in 2001. The title page has information on how to purchase it.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGiRN.jpg (I don't own it.)

Comment: @Alex Thanks. I’ll see if I can track down a copy.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact found in Eitz Chaim by Rabbi Chaim Vital. This appears to be either an error from the publisher or that Rabbi Yolles had a defective copy of Eitz Chaim as far as I can tell. The correct citation should read:

עצם [בעץ חיים, שער כד, שער פרקי הצלם, פרק ב, ד״ה והענין כי כל פרק ופרק כו׳](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14183&st=&pgnum=364)

Rabbi Yolles paraphrases closely the text of Rabbi Chaim Vital (which explains why the exact phrase searches came back with a null set) and all the details of his quotation are found there.

Thanks to those who offered assistance on this.